# Create "BETWEEN/AND"-capable DATETIMEs from given DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to create two `DATETIME` variables I can use to check with `BETWEEN AND` when given just one `DATETIME` in a stored procedure on SQL Server 2008.

So, when I get `2012/12/31 15:32:12` as input, I want to generate two new variables out of that, being `@from = 2012/12/31 00:00:00` and `@to = 2012/12/31 23:59:59`.

These two variables are used to check if the records lie between them - that is, are on the same day as the input date.

I fooled around using CAST and CONVERT, but I don't really konw how to manipulate the dates in the way I want.

Should I do this another way? Or are there functions I'm not aware of?

Comment: yep, better use >= and <

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now it is version independedt

```
declare @from datetime, @to datetime

SET @from = convert(varchar, convert(datetime, '2012/12/31 15:32:12', 111), 112)
SET @to = DATEADD(day, 1, @from)

select * from yourtable where test date >= @from AND date < @to
```

Comment: It tells me, `DATE is not a defined system type` -- is this version specific?

Comment: Now it is version independedt

Answer (score 2):

You can;

```
declare @input datetime = '2012/12/31 15:32:12'
declare @from  datetime = dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, @input))
declare @to    datetime = dateadd(second, -1, dateadd(day, 1, @from))

>>>
2012-12-31 00:00:00.000 2012-12-31 23:59:59.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of accuracy on your @to. 23:59:59.001 is a valid date but won't show up in your range if you subtract an entire second.

It is more common to set your @from and then use < @from + 1 instead of BETWEEN. (The plus adds whole days in SQL).

Answer (score 0):

First convert your input date to a varchar using the appropriate date format(111 in this case), For the to date, append the midnight hour

Then cast your varchar back to datetime.

Example :

```
SELECT @from = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) AS DATETIME)
      ,@to = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)+' 23:59:59:997' AS DATETIME)
```

Here is a useful chart of datetime formats with brief explanations.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx